# Swift error: "double is not convertible to UInt8"

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
var dvalue:Double = 1.03
var stok1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "stok") 
stok1.zRotation = dvalue * stok1.zRotation
```

This piece of code gives this error in the last line:
"Double is not convertible to UInt8"

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zRotation` is a CGFloat.

Your `dValue` is a Double.

They are not compatible. To multiply them, they must be same type: either both CGFloat or both Double. In this case, clearly CGFloat is desirable, since we will be assigning the result to a CGFloat.

Declare your `dValue` as a CGFloat, therefore, and all will be will.